# Vuetify - custom rule on v-text-field returns first element as undefined

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I used this rule to calculate the minimum purchase quantity and as long as this is not reached the form cannot be sent. The calculation itself works, but the first element is always "undefined".
Because the first element is "undefined", the number in the function `getSizesQuantity` is not correct if the value of the input field is 0.
What could be the reason for this?

product.json

```
{
    "sku": "12345",
    "name": "Product Name",
    "variants": [
        {
            "color": "White",
            "sku": "246420009",
            "colorimage": "path/to/image",
            "sizes": [
                {
                    "size": "XS",
                    "sku": "246420002"
                },
                {
                    "size": "S",
                    "sku": "246420003"
                },
                {
                    "size": "M",
                    "sku": "246420004"
                },
                {
                    "size": "L",
                    "sku": "246420005"
                },
                {
                    "size": "XL",
                    "sku": "246420006"
                },
                {
                    "size": "2XL",
                    "sku": "246420007"
                },
                {
                    "size": "3XL",
                    "sku": "246420008"
                },
                {
                    "size": "4XL",
                    "sku": "246420009"
                }
            ],
            "images": [
                {
                    "look": "front",
                    "packshot": "path/to/image"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

```
<v-form
    ref="form"
    v-model="isValid"
    lazy-validation
    @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
    <v-form ref="sizeform">
        <div class="grid-row sizes-col">
            <template v-for="(size, index) in variant.selected.sizes">
                <v-text-field
                    ref="sizeInputs"
                    :key="size.sku"
                    v-model.number="variantSize[index]"
                    :rules="sizeRules"
                    :label="size.size"
                    type="number"
                    min="0"
                    @change="(value) => setVariantSize(value, size, index)"
                    required />
            </template>
        </div>
    </v-form>
    <div class="small muted">
    * Mindestabnahme Menge 25 Stück / {{ getSizesQuantity }}
    </div>
</v-form>
```

```
data() {
    return {
        variant: this.activeVariant,
        variantSize: [],
        minimumSizesQuantity: 25,
        sizeQuantity: 0,
        sizeRules: [ (v) => {
                let totalQuantity = 0;

                console.log(this.$refs.sizeInputs && this.$refs.sizeInputs.length);

                if (this.$refs.sizeInputs && this.$refs.sizeInputs.length > 0) {
                    this.$refs.sizeInputs.forEach((input) => {
                        if (input.value) {
                            totalQuantity += parseInt(input.value, 10);
                            this.sizeQuantity = totalQuantity;
                        }
                    });
                }

                return totalQuantity >= this.minimumSizesQuantity;
            }
        ],
    };
},
computed: {
    getSizesQuantity() {
        return this.minimumSizesQuantity - this.sizeQuantity;
    },
},
```

this is the output of `console.log(this.$refs.sizeInputs && this.$refs.sizeInputs.length);`

```
undefined
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

Comment: What are you expecting? Why do you use the logical AND operator?

Comment: `$refs` are not available in `data()` function. They get added after reactivity (which is what `data()` is part of). Declare `sizeRules` as empty array and assign them your *"magic"* inside `mounted()`. Basically, your component needs to be mounted to have `$refs` (which are DOM references). `data()` is executed before mounting.

Comment: removing `this.$refs.sizeInputs` results in `[Vue warn]: Error in beforeMount hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"`

Comment: @tao: good to know. i will rewrite my code. thanks